# Exclude more than one condition with regex Scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I´m new with Scrapy

I want to exclude two elements in the same item. Below I´m excluding "SKU:", I wanna add "**sku**". I didn´t find the way.

```
'SKU': ready.xpath(SKU).re_first(r'SKU:\s*(.*)'), # Limpia SKU:
```

Anny suggestion? thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you want, but looks like you talk about regex that can run against both "SKU" and "sku". In `extract_first` you can use python compiled regular expression rather than string, so it could be done like this:

```
import re

re_sku = re.compile(r'sku:*\s*(.+)', re.IGNORECASE)

...
'SKU': ready.xpath(SKU).re_first(re_sku),
```